# How to create EditText accepts Alphabets only in android?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

How can I enter only alphabets in EditText in android?

Comment: Kotlin Solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947835/3333878

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
EditText state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtState);


                Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
                Matcher ms = ps.matcher(state.getText().toString());
                boolean bs = ms.matches();
                if (bs == false) {
                    if (ErrorMessage.contains("invalid"))
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "state,";
                    else
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "invalid state,";

                }
```

Comment: Great idea.. it helped me in making my own logic...  Thanks :)

Comment: What about space

Answer (score 203):

Add this line with your EditText tag.

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Your EditText tag should look like:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: what about non latin characters?

Comment: Not able to input space. How to allow single space in it

Comment: extra add this line for suggestion  android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"

Comment: after char  insertion if we try to add number it repeat previous char

Comment: use this to allow spaces too:
`android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "`

Comment: HI @Sandeep when i entered numeric value then it's not show but count so problem arise when i have set maxLength..

Comment: @vishalknishad If you put space at the end of a string it will be automatically trimmed off, but rather put the space in between your strings like this 
         `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa not sure, but it worked for me

Comment: Did anyone get abnormal behavior of blinking cursor? Blinking cursor is stuck at the start of the textbox.

Comment: nevermind, my `textAllCaps` was set to `true`.

Comment: does this work for multi lingual keyboards ?

Comment: What about characters like à, è, ù

Answer (score 63):

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
            if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                return src;
            }
            if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
                return src;
            }
            return edittext.getText().toString();
        }
    }
});
```

please test thoroughly though !

Comment: It didn't work for me. i did the same but when i enter numbers or special characters into EditText, it will remove all the characters which enter earlier. Why it is happen so?

Comment: @Nayana_Das That might be because of this line `return "";` . Replace that line with some text without the invalid character instead of returning an empty string.

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I type a number, if duplicates the text which is in the EditText. So if I had written "aba", it will put "abaaba" in the EditText.

Comment: when I press ( ) or number then it duplicates the data and this is a serious problem with that answer. Go for @swetabhSuman's answer.

Answer (score 30):

For those who want that their editText should accept only alphabets and space (neither numerics nor any special characters), then one can use this `InputFilter`.
Here I have created a method named `getEditTextFilter()` and written the InputFilter inside it.

```
public static InputFilter getEditTextFilter() {
        return new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                boolean keepOriginal = true;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    char c = source.charAt(i);
                    if (isCharAllowed(c)) // put your condition here
                        sb.append(c);
                    else
                        keepOriginal = false;
                }
                if (keepOriginal)
                    return null;
                else {
                    if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                        SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                        return sp;
                    } else {
                        return sb;
                    }
                }
            }

            private boolean isCharAllowed(char c) {
                Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
                Matcher ms = ps.matcher(String.valueOf(c));
                return ms.matches();
            }
        };
    }
```

Attach this inputFilter to your editText after finding it, like this :

```
mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{getEditTextFilter()});
```

The original credit goes to @UMAR who gave the idea of validating using regular expression and @KamilSeweryn

Comment: The Best answer. Have no idea why no more upvotes. android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" is the baddest solution cause android:imeOption not working with it.

Comment: @wonsuc what for?

Comment: As @mdzeko suggested: 
"^[a-zA-Z ]+$"   ->   "^[\\p{L} ]+$"
It works for me for Unicode.

Comment: Thank you man! You save my day! But it's not working on some devices (includes my - xiaomi redmi note 2), need remove suggestions for `EditText`. And the only way which work it's set `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`. Also I change `isCharAllowed(c)` function and make it without **Regex**. My way: `allowSymbols.contains(c, ignoreCase = true)`, where `allowSymbols` - a `string` with allowed characters.

Comment: This works and also helped me in discovering my own regex to use to get my solution, Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Through Xml you can do easily as type following code in xml (editText)...

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

**only characters will be accepted...**

Answer (score 11):

Put code edittext xml file,

```
   android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Answer (score 11):

For spaces, you can add single space in the digits. If you need any special characters like the dot, a comma also you can add to this list

> android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "

Answer (score 11):

**Allow only Alphabets in EditText android:**

```
InputFilter letterFilter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            String filtered = "";
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                char character = source.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isWhitespace(character)&&Character.isLetter(character)) {
                    filtered += character;
                }
            }

            return filtered;
        }

    };
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{letterFilter});
```

Comment: This worked as per my requirements after a couple more customizations. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/EditText1"
  android:text=""
  android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
  android:textSize="18sp"
  android:layout_width="80dp"
  android:layout_height="43dp">
</EditText>
```

Other inputType can be found 
 [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AutoCompleteTextView_inputType) ..

Answer (score 1):

If anybody still wants this, [Java regex for support Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode#10894689) is a good one. It's for when you want ONLY letters (no matter what encoding - japaneese, sweedish) iside an EditText. Later, you can check it using `Matcher` and `Pattern.compile()`

Answer (score 1):

- Just use the attribute `android:inputType="text"` in your xml file

EX:
if you want the user to provide an email address text:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_address"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

feel free to check many other input attributes using android studio's autocomplete feature:

[Auto complete Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O35K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simple  answer

EditText editTextName = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

if(!name.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {

editTextName.setError("Please enter only letters");

}

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
        new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                       int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                if (src.equals("")) {
                    return src;
                }
                if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                    return src;
                }
                String str = src.toString();
                str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
                return str;
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This Method

**For Java :**

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
yourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence cs, int start,
                int end, Spanned spanned, int dStart, int dEnd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(cs.equals("")){ // for backspace
             return cs;
        }
        if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
             return cs;
        }
        return "";
    }
}});
```

**For Kotlin :**

```
 val yourEditText = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.yourEditText) as EditText
    val reges = Regex("^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$")
    //this will allow user to only write letter and white space
    yourEditText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(
        object : InputFilter {
            override fun filter(
                cs: CharSequence, start: Int,
                end: Int, spanned: Spanned?, dStart: Int, dEnd: Int,
            ): CharSequence? {
                if (cs == "") { // for backspace
                    return cs
                }
                return if (cs.toString().matches(reges)) {
                    cs
                } else ""
            }
        }
    )
```