# android EditText alphabet-only validation

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

i wanted to validate a EditText and see if all of the letters are alphabet. it should be able to handle multiple EditText. i need a way to prevent user from entering anything other then alphabet.

```
        userTextInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textInput);
    userTextInput.addTextChangedListener(this);

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable edit) {
    String textFromEditView = edit.toString();
            //first method
    ArrayList[] ArrayList;
    //ArrayList [] = new ArrayList;
    for(int i=0; i<=textFromEditView.length(); i++)
    {
        if(textFromEditView[i].isLetter() == false)
        {
            edit.replace(0, edit.length(), "only alphabets");
        }
    }
            //second method
    try
    {
        boolean isOnlyAlphabet = textFromEditView.matches("/^[a-z]+$/i");
        if(isOnlyAlphabet == false)
        {
            edit.replace(0, edit.length(), "only alphabets");
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){}


}
```

for my second method the moment i enter anything, number or alphabet, my app crash. 
i have test my first method because it has the error textFromEditView must be an array type bue is resolved as string. can you help me to improve my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd do better using [InputFilter:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start, int end,
                                                   Spanned d, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                        if (!Character.isLetter(src.charAt(i))) { 
                                return src.subSequence(start, i-1); 
                        } 
                } 
                return null; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Code modified from: [How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android/4401227#4401227)

Comment: i found a good solution use. android:digits="qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM" /> in the xml. so far no problems. is the same link you gave me. thanks for the help!

Comment: Saw that too, but never tried it. If you're more satisfied with that, then don't hesitate to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

[How to create EditText accepts Alphabets only in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the inputType of the EditText. More Information [here](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html).

Comment: yes i knew these, but there do not have one that allows alphabet-only inputType.