# Android EditText : How to avoid user enter smileys?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I would like to avoid to the user to put a smiley with the keyboard into an `EditText`. Is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: can you say clearly pls?

Comment: you just want to avoid smilies and allow every thing or you just to allow text + numbers only (not special characters)? please clarify.

Comment: Yes, just want to avoid smilies and allow every thing

Comment: This question is quite obvious to me, why is this downvoted so much. Have a +1 on me

Comment: **Kotlin Solution here** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947835/3333878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your input type and only accept letters or change your keyboard type:

> > https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Or you can only accept some specific digits:

> > [How to create EditText accepts Alphabets only in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android)

Comment: What if those links are dead? Learn how to use SO.

Answer (score 13):

Editing answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030749/3119752).

This will allow only ASCII characters to be entered in EditText.

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
 new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
            return src;
        }
        if(src.toString().matches("[\\x00-\\x7F]+")){
            return src;
        }
        return "";
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: I simply did: `return source.toString().matches("\\S") ? source : "";` and it is working.
The \S allows anything but white-space (line breaks, tabs, spaces, hard spaces).

Comment: Working like charm! (Y)

Comment: but when you click emoji, then click backspace, 2 characters will be deleted from the current text