# How can I restrict EditText to take emojis

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I am developing an application where I want my edittext should take Name only. I have tried using   `android:inputType="textCapSentences"`  but it seems like its not working. My edittext is still taking the emojis.

So, Is there any way i can restrict any special character or emojis input in edit text in android.
If anyone have idea,Please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447928/android-edittext-how-to-avoid-user-enter-smileys and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android/9030749#9030749

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use emoji filter as code below

```
mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{EMOJI_FILTER});

public static InputFilter EMOJI_FILTER = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        boolean keepOriginal = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
        for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
            int type = Character.getType(source.charAt(index));
            if (type == Character.SURROGATE || type == Character.OTHER_SYMBOL) {
                return "";
            }
            char c = source.charAt(index);
            if (isCharAllowed(c)) 
                sb.append(c);
            else
                keepOriginal = false;
        }
        if (keepOriginal)
            return null;
        else {
            if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return sb;
            }
        }
    }
};

private static boolean isCharAllowed(char c) {
    return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) || Character.isSpaceChar(c);
}
```

Comment: but it will filter dot("."), comma(",") and other punctuation, not only emojis

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a trick, But I'm not sure that it could be helpful for your case. The trick is to set *inputType* as *textEmailAddress*

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Also you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23563582/6503228) .

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyListener keyListener = new TextKeyListener(TextKeyListener.Capitalize.SENTENCES, false);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                setInput(YOUR_EDIT_TEXT, keyListener, imm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a TextWatcher on editText, in OnTextChanged, do the following,

```
String s = charSequence.toString();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean b = m.find();
if(b == true){
 //give warning to user that special character is not allowed, 
//and delete or clear the last last character in charSequence .

}
```