# How to hide the smileys from the keyboard (Disable smileys icon)

Tags: android

I want to disable the smileys options from the keyboard, so that the user won't be able to enter any of the smiley. I tried the code and it works for me, but only in some devices. It didn't work on android 5.0. Please help

```
et_create_group.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: this helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560686/programmatically-hide-disable-emoticons-on-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: Didn't work in android 5.@Android

Comment: @I.d007 You can use input Filter , refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080149/how-can-i-restrict-edittext-to-take-emojis

Comment: "I want to disable the smileys options from the keyboard" -- that is not possible. The input method editor will do whatever it wants, and there are hundreds, if not thousands, of input method editors out there.