# How to disable fleksy keyboard auto-complete programmatically

Tags: android, keyboard

I used `EditText` as password input

```
   <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword|textNoSuggestions"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />
```

With native soft keyboard auto-complete is disabled and every things work as expected. But when using custom keyboard such as `Fleksy` auto-complete is enabled and I am not able to disable it pragmatically. I tried with the following steps.

1) `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"` with and without `textNoSuggestions`
2) Changed `EditText` to `autocompletetextview` and set adapter to null or empty array
 
3) `autocompletetextview` `setthreshold(100)`.

But nothing worked and password still appears in auto-complete. So do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40889381/115145 -- while that answer discusses emoji, instead of auto-complete, the results are the same. The behavior of auto-complete is between the soft keyboard developers and the user. You do not get a vote, beyond what you are doing already. For this specific keyboard, you could perhaps file a bug report with their developers, but there may be other keyboards that have similar issues.

Comment: It appears the keyboard you're using is broken.