# How to restrict emoji for textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello guy i'm finding for restrict emoji regex or input formatter for flutter.
i want to disable emoji in textfield if anybody have idea then please help me.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I dont think there are any availabilty as for now, what can you do is to create `MethodChannel` and in android call a method to do this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888902/how-to-disable-emojis-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: how can you solve using `MethodChannel` @Blasanka ?

Answer (score 13):

@magicleon94 pretty much answers your question, But I think my answer is worth mentioning that instead of restricting the unwanted emojis (Where the set is infinite), allow only the desired input characters (Where the set is finite). And luckily we have an input formatter built into flutter so we don't have to write one, its called
`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter()`

And simply use it like this

@deprecated

```
inputFormatters: [new WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]")),],
```

after flutter v1.20.0-1.0.pre the above
'WhitelistingTextInputFormatter' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Instead Use

```
inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]")),],
```

*The above input formatter only allows Alphabets in the input field and restricts all emojis for sure trust me :)*

Comment: I totally agree with you, just some days ago that formatter gave us problems in not allowing other symbols. I'm going to update my answer because it's not correct and may cause trouble. Thank you for bringing up again this!

Comment: @maheshmnj what would be RegExp to enable all Alphanumeric, Special char, only it should disable emoji

Comment: It should be something like this ```RegExp("[A-Za-z0-9#+-.]*")``` just put all the special characters you want inside the [ ].

Comment: This regexp indicates allow characters mentioned in the brackets and * at the end means 0 or more times.
if you had + instead of * it means 1 or more times.I would recommend you learning regex its fairly simple,useful in almost all areas of programming and interesting for sure.

Comment: I can't use space in my iOS simulator after implementing this :(

Comment: add '\/s' basically the Regexp should be `RegExp("[\/sa-zA-Z]")` this basically allows all alphabets and spaces

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

**THIS IS NOT CORRECT SINCE IT EXCLUDES SOME SYMBOLS AS WELL**

This formatter should do it:

```
BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
  RegExp(
    r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])'
  ),
),
```

Sorry for the bad formatting here!

Comment: Doesn't handle all emojis

Comment: E.g. this one  ️

Comment: @ebg11 its not possible to handle all the emojis they are never ending, focus on what you need hope my answer below makes sense :)

Answer (score 4):

I can't use space if using mahesh's answer in iOS emulator, I don't know why. so I modify mahesh's answer

```
var regexToRemoveEmoji =
    '   /\uD83C\uDFF4\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62(?:\uDB40\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73|\uDB40\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74|\uDB40\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67)\uDB40\uDC7F|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC69\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]))|\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83D\uDC68|(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]))|\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|(?:\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])\uFE0F|\uD83C\uDFFF|\uD83C\uDFFE|\uD83C\uDFFD|\uD83C\uDFFC|\uD83C\uDFFB)?|\uD83E\uDDD1(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE])|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF])|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF])|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF])|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF])|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC69\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|(?:\uD83D\uDC41\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])|\uD83C\uDFF3\uFE0F\u200D\u26A7|\uD83E\uDDD1(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])|\uD83D\uDC3B\u200D\u2744|(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC70\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD35\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD6-\uDDDD])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83D\uDC6F|\uD83E[\uDD3C\uDDDE\uDDDF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|(?:\u26F9|\uD83C[\uDFCB\uDFCC]|\uD83D\uDD75)(?:\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|\uD83C\uDFF4\u200D\u2620|(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC70\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD35\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD6-\uDDDD])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|[\xA9\xAE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u2328\u23CF\u23ED-\u23EF\u23F1\u23F2\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB\u25FC\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2618\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u2692\u2694-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A7\u26B0\u26B1\u26C8\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26E9\u26F0\u26F1\u26F4\u26F7\u26F8\u2702\u2708\u2709\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u2763\u2764\u27A1\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]|\uD83C[\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDE02\uDE37\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF2C\uDF36\uDF7D\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E\uDF9F\uDFCD\uDFCE\uDFD4-\uDFDF\uDFF5\uDFF7]|\uD83D[\uDC3F\uDCFD\uDD49\uDD4A\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73\uDD76-\uDD79\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA\uDECB\uDECD-\uDECF\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEF0\uDEF3])\uFE0F|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|\uD83C\uDFF3\uFE0F\u200D\uD83C\uDF08|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC67|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC15\u200D\uD83E\uDDBA|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C\uDFFF|\uD83C\uDFFE|\uD83C\uDFFD|\uD83C\uDFFC|\uD83C\uDFFB)?|\uD83C\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uD83C\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uD83C\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uD83D\uDC08\u200D\u2B1B|\uD83D\uDC41\uFE0F|\uD83C\uDFF3\uFE0F|\uD83E\uDDD1(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uD83C\uDDFF(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC])|\uD83C\uDDFE(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9])|\uD83C\uDDFC(?:\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8])|\uD83C\uDDFB(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDFA(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF9(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF8(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF7(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC])|\uD83C\uDDF5(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDF3(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF2(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF1(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDF0(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDEF(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5])|\uD83C\uDDEE(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9])|\uD83C\uDDED(?:\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDEC(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDEB(?:\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7])|\uD83C\uDDEA(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDE9(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDE8(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDE7(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDE6(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF])|[#\*0-9]\uFE0F\u20E3|(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC70\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD35\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD6-\uDDDD])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:\u26F9|\uD83C[\uDFCB\uDFCC]|\uD83D\uDD75)(?:\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C\uDFF4|(?:[\u270A\u270B]|\uD83C[\uDF85\uDFC2\uDFC7]|\uD83D[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66\uDC67\uDC6B-\uDC6D\uDC72\uDC74-\uDC76\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC83\uDC85\uDCAA\uDD7A\uDD95\uDD96\uDE4C\uDE4F\uDEC0\uDECC]|\uD83E[\uDD0C\uDD0F\uDD18-\uDD1C\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD30-\uDD34\uDD36\uDD77\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDBB\uDDD2-\uDDD5])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:[\u261D\u270C\u270D]|\uD83D[\uDD74\uDD90])(?:\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|[\u270A\u270B]|\uD83C[\uDF85\uDFC2\uDFC7]|\uD83D[\uDC08\uDC15\uDC3B\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66\uDC67\uDC6B-\uDC6D\uDC72\uDC74-\uDC76\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC83\uDC85\uDCAA\uDD7A\uDD95\uDD96\uDE4C\uDE4F\uDEC0\uDECC]|\uD83E[\uDD0C\uDD0F\uDD18-\uDD1C\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD30-\uDD34\uDD36\uDD77\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDBB\uDDD2-\uDDD5]|\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC70\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD35\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD6-\uDDDD]|\uD83D\uDC6F|\uD83E[\uDD3C\uDDDE\uDDDF]|[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDE01\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE36\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF20\uDF2D-\uDF35\uDF37-\uDF7C\uDF7E-\uDF84\uDF86-\uDF93\uDFA0-\uDFC1\uDFC5\uDFC6\uDFC8\uDFC9\uDFCF-\uDFD3\uDFE0-\uDFF0\uDFF8-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDC07\uDC09-\uDC14\uDC16-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3E\uDC40\uDC44\uDC45\uDC51-\uDC65\uDC6A\uDC79-\uDC7B\uDC7D-\uDC80\uDC84\uDC88-\uDCA9\uDCAB-\uDCFC\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD4B-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDDA4\uDDFB-\uDE44\uDE48-\uDE4A\uDE80-\uDEA2\uDEA4-\uDEB3\uDEB7-\uDEBF\uDEC1-\uDEC5\uDED0-\uDED2\uDED5-\uDED7\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF4-\uDEFC\uDFE0-\uDFEB]|\uD83E[\uDD0D\uDD0E\uDD10-\uDD17\uDD1D\uDD20-\uDD25\uDD27-\uDD2F\uDD3A\uDD3F-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD76\uDD78\uDD7A-\uDDB4\uDDB7\uDDBA\uDDBC-\uDDCB\uDDD0\uDDE0-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE74\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE90-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEB6\uDEC0-\uDEC2\uDED0-\uDED6]|(?:[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u270A\u270B\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDDE6-\uDDFF\uDE01\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE36\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF20\uDF2D-\uDF35\uDF37-\uDF7C\uDF7E-\uDF93\uDFA0-\uDFCA\uDFCF-\uDFD3\uDFE0-\uDFF0\uDFF4\uDFF8-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDC3E\uDC40\uDC42-\uDCFC\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD4B-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD7A\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA4\uDDFB-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECC\uDED0-\uDED2\uDED5-\uDED7\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF4-\uDEFC\uDFE0-\uDFEB]|\uD83E[\uDD0C-\uDD3A\uDD3C-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD78\uDD7A-\uDDCB\uDDCD-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE74\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE90-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEB6\uDEC0-\uDEC2\uDED0-\uDED6])|(?:[#\*0-9\xA9\xAE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26A7\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDDE6-\uDDFF\uDE01\uDE02\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF93\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E-\uDFF0\uDFF3-\uDFF5\uDFF7-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDCFD\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD49-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73-\uDD7A\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA4\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECB-\uDED2\uDED5-\uDED7\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF0\uDEF3-\uDEFC\uDFE0-\uDFEB]|\uD83E[\uDD0C-\uDD3A\uDD3C-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD78\uDD7A-\uDDCB\uDDCD-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE74\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE90-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEB6\uDEC0-\uDEC2\uDED0-\uDED6])\uFE0F|(?:[\u261D\u26F9\u270A-\u270D]|\uD83C[\uDF85\uDFC2-\uDFC4\uDFC7\uDFCA-\uDFCC]|\uD83D[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66-\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC81-\uDC83\uDC85-\uDC87\uDC8F\uDC91\uDCAA\uDD74\uDD75\uDD7A\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B-\uDE4F\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6\uDEC0\uDECC]|\uD83E[\uDD0C\uDD0F\uDD18-\uDD1F\uDD26\uDD30-\uDD39\uDD3C-\uDD3E\uDD77\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDBB\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD1-\uDDDD])/';
```

thats the regex, you can save it in separate file, and then use it in Text Field like this

```
TextField(
   inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(regexToRemoveEmoji))], 
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code, it will restrict all emojis.

```
inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])'))],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just needed letters and numbers, so I created a regexp to accept that:

```
final RegExp alphanumericRegex = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$');
```

And the TextField would be:

```
TextField(
  controller: _textEditingController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter text with numbers and letters only',
    errorText: _validateInput(_textEditingController.text),
  ),
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(_alphanumericRegex),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [remove_emoji_input_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/remove_emoji_input_formatter).
It works for me!

```
import 'package:remove_emoji_input_formatter/remove_emoji_input_formatter.dart';

TextField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    label: Text('Username')
  ),
  inputFormatters: [
    RemoveEmojiInputFormatter()
  ],
)
```