# Email field is accepting emojis

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

I'm using `RegExp` to validate email in one of my Flutter projects. Apparently, I'm able to insert, both by typing and copy-pasting, emojis in the email field. Below is the code for the email field:

```
Container(
  child: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: backgroundColor,
        hintColor: hintTextColor,
        primarySwatch: backgroundColorMaterial),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: provider.emailController,
      border: outlineBorderGrey,
      hintText: Translations.of(context).getEmail,
      labelText: Translations.of(context).getEmail,
      prefixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: provider.emailvalid ? emailFieldLogo : emailFieldLogoRed,
      ),
    ),
    inputFormatters: [ValidateHelper.emailRegex],
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  ),
),
```

);

The `inputFormatter` that I'm using is also a RegExp:

```
static TextInputFormatter emailRegex = BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'[!$#<>?":` ~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%A-Z]'));
```

After finishing the form, when I'm applying validation check on the email, the emojis are being accepted as valid input as well. The code for email validation is as follows:

```
bool isEmailValid(BuildContext context, String email) {
    Pattern patternEmail =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regexEmail = new RegExp(patternEmail);
    if (!regexEmail.hasMatch(email)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (email.isEmpty) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Is there any problem in the Regex pattern? Did I miss something out?

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are nothing but Characters. A  is U+1F601 in Unicode. And that Unicode is allowed with your Regex. You can restrict [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263801/how-to-restrict-emoji-for-textfield-in-flutter) is a question about restricting Emojis in a `Textfield`. Maybe that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to restrict entering emojis in email text field

```
inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                  r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
            ],
```