# Its posible to remove the smiley key in the android 10 keyboard?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-10.0

I want to remove the smilly key in the Android 10 keyboard.
[image]

I tried with diferent android:inputType in the EditText.

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|textShortMessage"
```

I don't want to forbid this creating a InputFilter in java code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable emojis programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888902/how-to-disable-emojis-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: There are hundreds of soft keyboard implementations, both pre-installed and user-installed. Their respective developers can do whatever they want. Some will have buttons like this, some will not. Things like `inputType` are hints that can and will be ignored or interpreted differently by different soft keyboards.

Comment: You can't do it for all keyboards maybe as @CommonsWare mentioned. Still, you can override `onTextChanged` or `filter` the input to get the desired result.