# How to implement Multiline EditText with ActionDone button (without Enter button)

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline, ime, imeoptions

I have EditText which is used for entering contents on messages (emails, sms). I want message to be immediately posted on ActionDone button click. I use following code for this:

```
message.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, i, keyEvent) -> {
            switch (i) {
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                    if (messageCanBePosted()) {
                        SoftKeyboard.hide(message);
                        postMessage();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

But also I want this message field to be multiline, like in any other messenger apps. I can achieve it with this line:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

The problem is that after adding this line ActionDone button starts acting like Enter button. So my callback for catching `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` is never called. So each time user press that button cursor moves to new line instead of posting message.

How can I keep both multiline behavior of EditText (ability to show text on multiple lines) and ActionDone button?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Finally, after searching here for similar threads I have found solution. Just need to add these lines on your Activity/Fragment:

```
editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
editText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

For some reason it doesn't work if you apply exact same setting from xml. You should do it programmatically.

There is also another possible solution - derive from EditText and apply `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` manually. But for me first solution looks simpler.

Comment: @silverFox yep, it worked for me. Which properties do you define for your EditText in xml?

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. I've been trying to do this for days and thought it was impossible. Thanks!

Comment: Finally! Deriving from EditText and applying DONE manually caused the editText to behave weirdly (loosing focus ignoring set text.. magic...) This simple solution worked like a charm.

Comment: this answer + editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) worked for me.. and in specific my case I also use digits field in xml (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android)

Answer (score 56):

Use

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

and in XML:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Source : [Multi-line EditText with Done action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986387/multi-line-edittext-with-done-action-button/41022589#41022589)

Comment: Only this one worked for me, and it worked like a charm - the Done button displayed & working, only a single line visible when an EditText is initially empty, and expanding to more lines when a user types in OR there's more text added initially from the code (setText).

Comment: It would have been nice to cite the source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41022589/4607733

Comment: Thanks, after searching for hours, you were right, it does not work only by changing xml. What a mess...

Comment: At last, worked! This is magic for me, years and years with this horrible bug in xml EditText properties!

Comment: For multi-line URL text entry fields, this is what worked for me: `editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI); editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);` and you don't need to specify anything in the EditText XML properties. Some keyboards adapt to this InputType by showing suggestions of web addresses, or displaying a ".com" key.

Answer (score 20):

Continuing *Ruslan*'s answer. The trick worked but there is one more thing that you need to take care of in XML.

`EditText` should have input type `text` otherwise `actionDone` won't work. Default input type of `EditText` does allow user to input line breaks so inputType should be set to `text` i.e.

```
android:inputType="text"
//And of course
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

And in your java class you need to add:

```
editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```

Comment: inputType=text & imeOptions=actionDone in xml and setHorizontallyScrolling() in the code did it! Thanks, at last.

Answer (score 0):

### Reuseable Kotlin Solution

Setting these values ***in code*** worked for me, thanks to the other answers

```
edittext.inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
edittext.setHorizontallyScrolling(false)
edittext.maxLines = Integer.MAX_VALUE // Or your preferred fixed value
```

I require this frequently, so made this to keep the code clean:

```
fun EditText.multilineIme(action: Int) {
    inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
    horizontalScroll(false)
    maxLines = Integer.MAX_VALUE
}

// Then just call
edittext.multilineIme(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
```

If you want to be add an optional custom action on 'Done', try this:

```
fun EditText.multilineDone(callback: (() -> Unit) = null) {
    val action = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
    multilineIme(action)
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
            if (action == actionId) {
                callback?.invoke()
                true
            }
            false
        }
    }
}

// Then you can call
edittext.multilineDone { closeKeyboard() }

// or just
edittext.multilineDone()
```