# Edittext in multiline with actionDone issue in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

`Edittext` in set input type multi-line when action Done not working.

I have tried each code that you mentioned in solution, but still I am facing the same issue. How can I resolve it?

How to implement Multiline EditText with ActionDone button (without Enter button) this answer tried in my app, but not working so.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36346471/5110595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

in XML:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```