# android:Kotlin EditText android:digits not working

Tags: android, kotlin

may be it is easy question but i am new to android

i have Edit text with android:digits is set but it is ignored and the text accepts all chars

```
  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:alpha=".7"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_border_gray_transprent"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_tv"
                android:inputType="text" />
```

the  edittext should accept only chars but now it accept all (numbers,chars, symbols)

why ?

Thanks for helping

Edit
this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android) is not duplicate it take the contents of the text then validate my requirement that the text does not accept symbols at all it should be done by android:digits but for some reason it does not work

Comment: No still accepts numbers and symbols

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create EditText accepts Alphabets only in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android)

Comment: the accepted answer work but the editText accept any symbols and number then it validate the contents i mean it does not prevent but android:degits prevent entering symbols (or it should prevent) that's what i need